# How to prove that every partial elementary map can be extended to an automorphism?

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal M$ be a structure whose domain is $M$.
If $f$ is a partial elementary map $f:A\subseteq M\to M$, I want to find an elementary extension $\mathcal N$ of $\mathcal M$ and an automorphism $f'\in\mathop{\mathrm{Aut}}\mathcal N$ such that $f'$ extends $f$.

I already proved some pretty similar results (for example the fact that if $\mathcal{M}_1\equiv\mathcal{M}_2$, then $\mathcal{M}_1\preceq\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}_2\preceq\mathcal{N}$ for some structure $\mathcal{N}$) but I struggle with this one.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what you tried during your struggles.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I tried to iterate creating bigger and bigger maps applying the result I mentioned at the end of my question to A and M itself and considering the union of them but without clear results

Comment: Well, that sounds like a good strategy! If your issue is obtaining surjectivity, I'll give you the hint: "back-and-forth".

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for the hint but this is an exercise in my course that appears before back-and-forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prove the following lemma:

**Lemma:** For any stucture $M$ and any partial elementary map $f\colon A\to M$ with $A\subseteq M$, there exists an elementary extension $M\preceq N$ and a partial elementary map $g\colon M\to N$ extending $f$.

Now construct a chain $(M_i,f_i)_{i\in \omega}$ with the following properties:

- $M_0 = M$ and $f_0 = f$.
- For all $i$, $M_i \preceq M_{i+1}$ and $f_{i+1}$ extends $f_i$.
- For all even $i$, $f_{i+1}$ is a partial elementary map with domain  $M_i$.
- For all odd $i$, $f_{i+1}$ is a partial elementary map with range $M_i$.

For the even steps, apply the Lemma to $f_i$. For the odd steps, apply the Lemma to $f_i^{-1}$.

Then $N = \bigcup_{i\in \omega} M_i$ is an elementary extension of all the $M_i$, and $f' = \bigcup_{i\in \omega} f_i$ is a partial elementary map extending all the $f_i$. Because of the even steps, every element of $N$ is in the domain of $f'$, and because of the odd steps, every element of $N$ is in the range of $f'$. So $f'$ is an automorphism of $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already proved that lemma so it is exactly what I needed